# Apache > Proxy > How to forward HTTP request with POST data

Tags: apache, proxy

I plan to use the Apache proxy module i.e. mod_proxy to forward an incoming HTTP POST request from a jump machine to another server inside a LAN.

I succeeded in forwarding pure HTTP request, but with the POST data I do not know why it just does not work.

My settings in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf looks something like:

```
 ProxyRequests On
 ProxyVia On
 <Proxy *>
 Order deny,allow
 Allow from all
 </Proxy>
 ProxyPass /oozie/start_wf http://168.17.1.204:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start
 ProxyPassReverse /oozie/start_wf http://168.17.1.204:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start
```

Is there anything more I need to add to this part of configuration?

Comment: First one question: why a `GET` parameter if you want to proxy a `POST` request?

Comment: Second one hint: Usually the `ProxyPass/ProxyPassReverse` combination is enough, why the rest above? And `ProxyRequests` should almost always be set to `Off`.

Comment: the get parameter is for the special Oozie request. A direct request forwarding command without forwarding is something like: curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d @wf_config.xml "http://data-xx:11000/oozie/v1/jobs?action=start"

Comment: Can you clarify what happens with the POST data?

Comment: I got the following debug: * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 52.16.15.75...
* Connected to front-01.development.battery (52.16.15.75) port 80 (#0)
> POST /oozie/start_workflow HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.38.0
> Host: front-01.development.battery
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/xml
> Content-Length: 768
> 
* upload completely sent off: 768 out of 768 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Date: Fri, 08 Jan 2016 08:53:33 GMT
* Server Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
< Content-Length: 218
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

Answer (score 0):

The following entry on **httpd.conf** file should work.

```html
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ServerName mycompany.com
  ServerAlias mycompany.com  
  ProxyPass /appServer http://<application_server_ip>:<port>
  ProxyPassReverse /appServer http://<application_server_ip>:<port>
  Redirect "/login" "/appServer/<application_context_root>/login"
  Redirect "/logout" "/appServer/<application_context_root>/logout"
  <Directory "/var/www/html">
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```